Please clearly indicate to users that they can only reply to a mod message once (unless their message is replied to)
When a mod message is sent to a user, they are only allowed one reply unless the mods respond to their reply. I’d imagine that many users who have received a mod message may not know this, and may make a quick reply such as “Okay” which will then prevent them from actually making a “real” response to the message later on. Indeed, the drop-down of "What is a moderator message?", says that it is a "conversation", which makes it seem even less likely that there is a 1 message limit.
I think that it would be helpful if there was a clear message somewhere warning users of this. Could this be implemented?


There already is such a warning. The UI for mod messages, last I checked, does warn users that they only get only one reply. Whether they read that is another question. Could it be improved... possibly. I kinda thought it had been when we redid the mod message UI a year or so ago. Unfortunately, I don't know what it currently looks like. A "confirmation" popup before sending the message might be helpful but many people don't read those, either. This question would be improved by showing an example of the current UI.

@Catija here a screenshot of the mod message UI

... weird. I swear we added something. Maybe it was in a draft that never got built... And it's not at the top of the page or anything? ... this has just been one of my biggest frustrations and I don't understand why it wouldn't have been changed if we did end up making those updates... That said, I don't think that screenshot looks like the proposed design, so maybe we never shipped it.

@Catija nope, not at the top of the page...

SO mod here: there is indeed no such warning, nor has any idea to implement such a warning ever been conveyed to mods - at least not that I can find, and I've checked all the internal docs related to the rollout of the mod message UI updates from last year. It likely never became anything more than an SE-internal draft.

It might be helpful to just allow sending more than one message.

@MisterMiyagi then we get the user who keeps spamming death threats...

@Starship Make it two, then, or one per hour, or something similar. If SO proves one thing, it’s that the people who should read such messages are those that don’t.

@Catija I can't even find the warning in the current moderator UI. I agree that I've seen something like it before (either from a sender or receiver POV), and not in a FAQ here on Meta.SE, or (I just checked) in one moderator-specific Help Center article where it is mentioned.

Not to mention that anyone who does read the sidebar blurb there is told that a mod message is a "private, confidential conversation", which sounds like the furthest possible thing from "you get only one message, don't waste it".

@MisterMiyagi 2 wouldn’t ultimately solve the problem, what if a user sends “Okay” and then in a new message “Thank you for letting me know”? And 1 once per hour…then you have the troll who makes a bot to bombard the mods once per hour.

@Starship ultimately it would be better served if the message system acted like a support system, where the mod message is active and allows responses for a given window (i.e. so long as people are responding to it). Eventually the message would get closed, meaning noone can reply to it further. It could be closed automatically (lack of activity), or by the moderator/CM team if it's being abused.

@Robotnik Auto-Closure would be a problem. What if the user only sees the message a month later?

@Starship well if they were warned of something, then they move on. If they were banned for 7 days->1 month, then they missed their ban term because they've been away during it anyway. If they're banned for >1 month -> a year, they'll have to use the "contact us" form to appeal it to the CM team). But ultimately, it's a contrived scenario: either the user is active enough - they'll see the message and can respond. Or they're not active enough, in which case it's unlikely they'll be getting a 1 year suspension, or they won't care enough that they did.

@Robotnik what if they were warned of something and were simply on vacation at the time...

@Starship - the fallback is to escalate beyond the mod team, which is also the escalation path if you take issues with what mods do when not on vacation :). We also don't have to assume 1 month expiry - what about 90 days? Half a year? Surely there's a point where the user's lack of email-checking catches up to them and we can consider a situation closed.

@MisterMiyagi A) the user and moderators should be clearly informed within the UI what restrictions the system will place on the interactions (e.g., that the user only gets 1 reply). B) I'd be OK with changing things to allow up to two replies to the first mod message in the "conversation", and an additional reply if the last message in the "conversation" was from a moderator. Basically, it's reasonable to allow for a user to send an "OK" message, and then a more comprehensive reply, once, but we shouldn't leave moderators open to unlimited abuse, which would happen.

@Makyen We get them to set a minimum character length to "count" for a first response. If it's under 20 characters, they can send a second one. :D

Then you have the user who says "Thank you for telling me" @Catija

I mean, considering I thought SO'd already done this and Makyen's comment says that the UI should warn people about it, my comment is just supplementary, not really an alternative.

@Catija perhaps we could have a button where the mods could toggle a user being able to respond more times or as much as they want....also what if a user curses the mod with under 20 characters...
